# crear json con valores seleccionados desde checkbox Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla html cargada dinámicamente, donde en la última columna hay un checkbox para cada fila.

La tabla la lleno con jquery ajax de esta forma:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: base_url + 'animales/get-by-lote-and-est/'+idLoteActual+'/'+idEstablecimiento,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#tablaAnimalesLotes th').remove();
                    $("#tablaAnimalesLotes thead").append("<th>ID</th><th>Sexo</th><th>Fecha</th><th></th>");
                    $('#tablaAnimalesLotes tr').remove();
                    $.each(data, function(i, item){
                    $('<tr>').html(
                        "<td>"+data[i].id +"</td><td>"+ data[i].sexo + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i].fecha+ "</td>"+
                         "<td><input type='checkbox' value="+data[i].id+ " name='chk' id='chkBox" + i + "' /></td></tr>").appendTo('#tablaAnimalesLotes');
                    });
                }
            });
```

Los input que tienen los otros datos son log siguientes:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDato1">
<input type="text" id="txtDato2">
```

Con este código capturo los ID de cada fila seleccionada mediante los check

```
            var ids = [];
            $.each($("input[name='chk']:checked"), function(){
                ids.push($(this).val());
            });
```

Esto me genera un array pero ademas necesito que por cada fila tambíen vayan otros datos que son fijos, sacados de unos input text.
La idea es que al final, al presionar el button teniendo los check seleccionados por el usuario deberia quedar algo asi, suponiendo se seleccionaron sólo esos dos checkbox de la tabla:

```
[{"id": "idCheck1","dato1": "valor de input 1","dato2": "valor de input 2"} 
 {"id": "idCheck2","dato1": "valor de input 2","dato2": "valor de input 2"}
]
```

Por favor como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un [mcve]? Dices que necesitas agregar datos *sacados de unos input text*. Añade el código `HTML` de tu formulario o página. Saludos

Comment: Para ayudar se necesita por lo menos un ejemplo del codigo HTML que contiene los inputs (checkbox y textos) que generan las filas para ver como estan relacionados.

Comment: actualicé la información, espero ser mas claro ahora

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    let ids=[];
    // valida que exista o no el elemento
    function validate(arr,ids){
     //recorre el arreglo
     for(x in arr){
      //retorna la posicion si existe
      if(arr[x].id === ids) return true
     }
     // retorna false si no la encuentra
    return false
    }
    // remueve del arreglo
    function remove(arr,ids){
    // recorre el arreglo
     for(x in arr){
     // si existe
      if(arr[x].id === ids){
        // remueve la posicion
         arr.splice(x, 1);
         return true;
        }
     }
     // si no existe
    return false
    }


    $("#tablaAnimalesLotes").on("click","input[name='chk']", function(){
       // valida que no exista en el arreglo
        if(!validate(ids,$(this).attr("id"))){
         // lo agrega
          ids.push({ "id":$(this).attr("id") ,
                       "dato": "valor de input "+$(this).attr("id")});
        }else{
           // remueve en caso de que exista
           remove(ids,$(this).attr("id"))
        }
        // imprimimos
        console.log(ids)
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablaAnimalesLotes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="txtDato1" name="chk">
    <input type="checkbox" id="txtDato2" name="chk">
</div>
```

Comment: la funcion: $("input[name='chk']").on("click", function() .... no reconoce los checkbox de la tabla: input type='checkbox' value="+data[i].id+ " name='chk' id='chkBox" + i + "' /></td>  si embargo cuando pruebo creando checks fijos como en el ejemplo que indicas funcionan bien.

Comment: ya lo corregi utiliza [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Donde usas delegate?

Comment: en esta linea `$("#tablaAnimalesLotes").on("click","input[name='chk']", function(){` si vez el manual de `jquery` para las versiones `1.7+ ` se incluye dentro de `on` pasandolo como segundo argumento del evento